# ConvNetSharp - using Dropout

Tags: c#, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convnetsharp

I would like to try adding a dropout layer in my model but I get this error on **Train** method:

**Volume should have a Shape [1] to be converter to a System.Double**

What did I do wrong? I would also like to know how to "disable" the dropout layer **when I'm not in training** (testing).

```
SgdTrainer trainer;
int numFeatures = 3;
Net<double> net = new Net<double>();
Volume<double> inputVolume, outputVolume;

trainer = new SgdTrainer(net) { LearningRate = 0.0001, BatchSize = 128 };

// 4 test cases with 3 features each    
double[] inputData = new double[12]  { 0, 1, 2,   3, 4, 5,   6, 7, 8,   6, 7, 8 };

// binary classification: 0,1 = is class; 1,0 = not class    
double[] outputData = new double[8]  { 0, 1,      1, 0,      0, 1,      1, 0 };

net.AddLayer(new InputLayer(1, 1, numFeatures));

net.AddLayer(new FullyConnLayer(10));
net.AddLayer(new ReluLayer());

net.AddLayer(new DropoutLayer(0.5)); // (ಠ_ಠ)

net.AddLayer(new FullyConnLayer(2));
net.AddLayer(new SoftmaxLayer(2));

inputVolume = BuilderInstance.Volume.From(inputData, new Shape(1, 1, numFeatures, inputData.Length / numFeatures));
outputVolume = BuilderInstance.Volume.From(outputData, new Shape(1, 1, 2, outputData.Length / 2));  

trainer.Train(inputVolume, outputVolume); // get error if there is dropout above
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Volume should have a Shape [1] to be converter to a System.Double

This error was due to a bug recently introduced in ConvNetSharp. It was fixed in PR [#133](https://github.com/cbovar/ConvNetSharp/pull/133)

> I would also like to know how to "disable" the dropout layer when I'm not in training

Dropout layer knows when you are training or evaluating the model. It will drop and scale inputs when necessary.